Floating Action Button displayed the wrong position in the real device
I created an activity with the BottomAppBar and Floating Action Button based on the guide. When I ran it in the Genymotion, it worked as well as I expected.
In the Genymotion
But when I exported it to apk file and installed to Xiaomi device (MIUI 13 - Android 12 SKQ), it didn't work as I expected (deviate to the left).
In the Xiaomi Device
I don't know what the reason is.
This is my xml source code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/draw_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black">
        
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameMainContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
                android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/red"
                app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
                app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="50dp">
                <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/bottomNavMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
            </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabCenter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_circle_outline_24"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"/>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navViewDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/app_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_navigation_menu"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

I have tried to research something but no article say about it.
I hope I will receive the solution for my issue

I have found the answer.
The root cause is that the theme was set incorrectly.
(In virtual machine, the night theme is used but in the real devivce, the dark theme is used)
